# How to choose between openH264 and x264 decoder

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

I'm using the dev build from zeranoe.com which has OpenH264 and libx264 in it.
How can i choose between these two Decoders to compare the decoding speed ?

```
avcodec_find_decoder(AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
```

only gives me the name "h264"
but which decoder is it ?

And tries to force a specific decoder failed, like:

```
codec = avcodec_find_decoder _by_name("x264");
codec = avcodec_find_decoder _by_name("libx264");
```

Which other options i have to improve the decoding speed of avcodec_decode_video2 for highres (4k and higher) RTSP video streams ?

Comment: x264 and openH264 are encoders. AFAIK, ffmpeg only uses its native `h264` decoder to decode.

Comment: `x264` is encoder only, open `OpenH264` both encoder and decoder. So you either decode with built-in ffmpeg h264 decoder or with libopenh264 decoder. Decoding with x264 is currently not possible.

Answer (score 10):

FFmpeg can use OpenH264 (named `libopenh264` in FFmpeg) to decode in addition to the native FFmpeg H.264 decoder (named `h264`). There are also several supported [hardware assisted H.264 decoders](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro), but I'm not going to go into detail about those.

## OpenH264 vs FFmpeg H.264 decoder

- The documentation states that [OpenH264 supports decoding of Constrained Baseline profile](https://github.com/cisco/openh264#decoder-features), so its usefulness may be limited. However it was able to decode a Main and a High profile video I tested. The actual capabilities appear to be undocumented, so it is unclear if it has partial or full support for Main and High profiles.
- The native FFmpeg H.264 decoder has threading capabilities (frame and slice) but OpenH264 does not. So the FFmpeg H.264 decoder is much faster than OpenH264.
- OpenH264 is licensed BSD 2-Clause "Simplified" License. FFmpeg H.264 decoder is LGPL 2.1 or later.

## `ffmpeg` CLI tool examples

It appears you're working with the FFmpeg libraries, but here are some examples using `ffmpeg`.

To choose the decoder you want use the `-c:v` input option. Below are two decoding benchmark examples using the [null muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null). The `-map` option is also used so only the (first) video stream is decoded and to ignore other, non-video streams such as audio.

### Native FFmpeg H.264 decoder

```
$ ffmpeg -benchmark -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -f null -
bench: utime=23.557s
bench: maxrss=57752kB
real    0m3.834s
user    0m23.573s
sys     0m0.213s
```

### libopenh264

```
$ ffmpeg -benchmark -c:v libopenh264 -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -f null -
bench: utime=20.927s
bench: maxrss=37404kB
real    0m21.002s
user    0m20.940s
sys     0m0.060s
```

## Benchmark time

Note the benchmark option outputs user CPU time, not the elapsed real time. If you want real time as well add the `time` command before the `ffmpeg` command (if you're on Linux). I added the outputs from `time` in the example (the last three lines) for comparison purposes.

## To verify the desired decoder is being used

View the console output. For example using the native H.264 decoder:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
```

Using libopenh264:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (libopenh264) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
```

Comment: Weird. `ffmpeg -h decoder=h264` does not show openh264 as a decoder.